# How can I validate & beautify JSON through a jquery/javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonlint

I have a requirement where in I get JSON data from backend and I have to show that in textarea.currently, the data comes but its not formatted and validated.Now

1)How can I beautify JSON in the textarea ?
2)How can I validate it before saving ?

I have searched for all javascript/jquery plugins but I am not getting what I want.I want something like jslint

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to check that a string is a valid representation of a JSON object:

```
function parseJson(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var parsed = parseJson(someInput);
if (parsed === false) {
    // Invalid json
}
```

If you also need to validate the object using some custom logic (e.g. "I need your object to have attributes X and Y"), take a look at [JsonSchema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema).

Answer (score 14):

Use [`JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with space parameter for a formatted JSON string.

```js
var object = [{ "stop_id": 70021, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION", "stop_lat": 37.757692, "stop_lon": -122.392318, "zone_id": 3329 }, { "stop_id": 70022, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION", "stop_lat": 37.757692, "stop_lon": -122.392318, "zone_id": 3329 }, { "stop_id": 70151, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - ATHERTON STATION", "stop_lat": 37.464458, "stop_lon": -122.198152, "zone_id": 3331 }];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nice! Never heard of it